# What does + '0' mean in C

Tags: c

I have this line:

```
binary[index] = (tempDecimal % 2) + '0';
```

Could you explain the usefulness of `+ '0'` in this line of code for me?

Comment: While this question is about [tag:C] and the other one about [tag:C++], they indeed are about the same effect.

Comment: Yes, this C question should not be marked as a duplicate of the C++ question. While both standards have effectively the same rule, C has the rule because the C standard says so, and C++ has the rule because the C++ standard says so.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I agree here. While there are places in the C++ standard that defer to a specific C standard (e.g., C11), this is not one of those places.