# Converting integer to string in C

Tags: c, string, type-conversion

```
int x =5;
char y = x + '0';
```

Apparently this bit of code converts an integer to a string. But I don't understand how it works behind the scenes. I'm a newbie. Could someone explain how adding a string 0 with an int converts it into a string?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does adding a '0' to an int digit allow conversion to a char?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24422178/why-does-adding-a-0-to-an-int-digit-allow-conversion-to-a-char)

Comment: duplicates: [What does + '0' mean in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54750403/995714), [Converting an integer to char by adding '0' - what is happening?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30029294/995714)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

> `char y = x + '0';`

put the character code (ASCII or whatever character code your system implements) of `'0'` and add `5` to it then again convert that integer to an ASCII(*/UTF-8 or any other character encoding*) character that's what your output(`5`) will be.

Behind the scenes this is what's happening:

```
y = 5 + 48  ;for ASCII/UTF-8 character code of '0' is 48
y = 53
```

and ASCII/UTF-8 char for `53` is `'5'`.

It does not convert a string to an integer. It just gives you the equivalent character.
We can convert an `int(0-127)` to a `char` or vice-versa, output will be an ASCII/UTF-8 value. `char` are stored as `short int` in memory. i.e. they are `8-bit int` values.

Answer (score 0):

You have a bit of misunderstanding here. The variable `y` isn't string, it's a char. string is an array of chars. What you are actually doing here is:

```
char y = x + 48; //48 is the ASCII encoding of 0
```

This is somewhat like:

```
char y = 50;
printf("%c\n", y); //prints 2 as a char
```

This is because chars are encoded with a specific value. Eg. `'a'` is 97. `'b'` is 98 and so on. The same way '0''s code is 48.

```
 char y = x + '0'
```

means is adding the encoded value of `0`(ie 48) to x. And because `0` is the first number, the other number's code will be right next to it. This is what I mean:

```
48 -> This is 0
49 -> This is 1
50 -> This is 2
51 -> This is 3
52 -> This is 4
53... and so on
```

You may notice that in order to get eg. 1, we need to add one to zero. `48 + 1 = 49` and 49 is the encoding for 1. This is true for all numbers.

Note: I've used ASCII encoding for explaining but there are others and it should work on most on weird encodings.

Comment: Re “it should work on most on weird encodings”: Adding the value of a digit (0-9) to `'0'` works in all C implementations that conform to the C standard, because the standard requires the character codes for the digits to be consecutive.

Answer (score -1):

`'0'` is an int, not a string. String literals have double quotes (e.g. `"Hi!"`). Character literals (which are integers) have single quotes (e.g. `'A'`).

`x + '0'` evaluates to `int` since both the operands are `int`.

The integral value of a character literal is its ASCII value : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Character_set
From the ascii table, the integer value of '0' is 48.

Now, coming to the expression in the question:
x is 5, '0' is 48.
Therefore y = 48+5 (i.e 53).

When you print `y` as a character using `printf("%c", y)`, the character whose ASCII value is 53 is printed. i.e. `'5'`

Why adding `'0'` to a single digit integer seems to convert it into an integer is because '0' to '9' are one after another in the ASCII table. This means `'9'` (57) is exactly 9 spaces after `'0'` (48).

This is why adding double digit integers to '0' will not work. E.g. '0' + 10 will be `':'` (ASCII value 58).

To properly convert larger strings to integers, use the atoi function (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/atoi.3.html).
e.g.

```
int a = atoi("1023"); // a is an integer with the value 1023
```

Comment: `That means it can take values from -128 to 127` that's completely wrong. `char` [can be signed or unsigned](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2054939/995714) and can contain more than 8 bits of data. So `char` can contain values in the range [0, 2^CHAR_BIT] if it's unsigned, and [-2^(CHAR_BIT/2), 2^(CHAR_BIT/2) - 1] if signed

Comment: *`'0'` is a character*  [Actually it's an integer](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.4p10): "An integer character constant has type `int`. ..."

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @phuclv and @Andrew !     

I've always assumed that `char` is signed by default and takes exactly 8 bits (Since `uint8_t` typedefs to `unsigned char`. Did not know that even _that_ is implementation specific).   
Also did not know that `'0'` is an `int`. (Why is that? Wouldn't it be more efficient to use `char`?)    


Anyways, I'm updating the answer to fix those issues. If it still does not provide value, please let me know. I will delete it.

Comment: @RehanVipin `uintN_t` are optional types and `uint8_t` only exists if `CHAR_BIT == 8`. Only `(u)int_fastN_t` and `(u)int_leastN_t` are required. I don't know why character C decides that character literals should be int, but probably because of multicharacter literals like `'abcd'` which were commonly used for signatures like [FourCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FourCC), and because of integer promotion. But in C++ `'0'` is `char`: [Why are C character literals ints instead of chars?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/433895/995714)